# How do I avoid a race condition in Jasmine tests when using static members?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have Jasmine tests that are run with Karma. These tests cover an object with static properties that are used to control behavior. Altering these static properties has detrimental effects for tests that do not expect them to deviate from the default. More concretely, this test:

```
it('honors the base64CharactersPerLine option', () => {
    const testData = new Uint8Array([ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 ]);
    const pem = new PEMObject();
    pem.header = "CERTIFICATE";
    pem.data = testData;
    PEMObject.base64CharactersPerLine = 1; // Causes race condition
    const encodedData = pem.encode();
    console.info(encodedData);
    console.info(encodedData.match(/^\w/g));
    expect(encodedData.match(/^\w$/g).length).toBeGreaterThan(testData.length);
});
```

is adversely affecting this test:

```
it('decoding then encoding returns the original data', () => {
    const pem = new PEMObject();
    pem.header = "CERTIFICATE";
    pem.decode(testPEM);
    expect(pem.encode()).toEqual(testPEM);
});
```

by making the output of `pem.encode()` in the latter test not identical to the original input `testPEM` (a `string`).

The more general question I would like to know is: **how do you prevent race conditions in Karma/Jasmine tests where static members are used to modify behavior?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a race condition and not just an issue that you're modifying the object which many tests use?

You can perhaps save the old value of the `base64CharactersPerLine` field before the test is run and restore it afterwards, so that other tests see the *right* value.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a new value to a static value in a test will affect all other tests that run later.

There are two ways to fix this. First, in a `beforeEach` block, cache the original value of the static property, and then reset it in an `afterEach` block. Like this:

```
let cachedValue;
beforeEach(() => cachedValue = PEMObject.base64CharactersPerLine);
afterEach(() => PEMObject.base64CharactersPerLine = cachedValue);
```

This will work, but will be complicated to maintain and reason about if you have lots of static properties you are manipulating during your tests.

A better approach is to change from using static properties and use static methods instead (though this requires a change to your base code).  Once using static methods, you can then use jasmine spies, which are cleaned up after each test run. So, you would do something like this:

```
// in your base code
PEMObject.getBase64CharactersPerLine = () => SOME_VALUE;

// in your 'honors the base64CharactersPerLine option' test
spyOn(PEMObject, 'getBase64CharactersPerLine').and.returnValue(1);
```

And you no longer need `beforeEach`/`afterEach` blocks.